# Event "systemevents.timechanged", but by how much has the time changed?

Tags: c#, windows, time

There are nearly 50 questions on StackOverflow that mention this Windows system event, many of which also mention possible issues around clearing the culture & timezone caches, and a known bug of firing twice. I have not found anything that will let me know what the time was immediately prior to the event. I would have hoped that the C# version of this included that in the event args, but apparently not since this is just a thin wrapper. Periodically saving "now" and comparing to that would work, but is neither elegant nor liable to be very precise in practice.

Is there some Windows function or some other, better way of determining what the time was before the change?

Comment: At least on Windows 10, the kernel will log time changes in the system event log with a message of the form "The system time has changed to ‎2017‎-‎10‎-‎26T21:07:40.450000000Z from ‎2017‎-‎10‎-‎26T21:07:39.913003200Z.", and the XML of that event contains the old time and the new time in structured form. I suppose this is an ETW event too (of the Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General provider) that you could listen for with an `EventProviderTraceListener`. More work to set up than a simple event handler, of course, and portability is a thing.

Comment: All the "common" solutions (including `SystemEvents.TimeChanged`) simply listen for a broadcast `WM_TIMECHANGE` system message. Those approaches can't know what the old time was since the message simply doesn't include it. It has the benefit of working on all current versions of Windows, though (prior to Windows 2000, applications had to broadcast this message themselves; from 2000 onwards it's system generated).

Comment: Can you just capture the current time at application startup? Then whenever the time is changed, you'll know what the previous time was. And when it's changed, capture it again, and that's the previous time if it changes again, etc.

Comment: @ScottHannen: And how would you calculate the offset, i.e. by how much the time was changed? All you have is the current time (after the change), and some arbitrary earlier timestamp, relative to a different epoch.

Comment: Capture and compare UTC.

Comment: @ScottHannen: UTC doesn't help. It's just a constant offset, both in the old and newly set epoch.